# How to use the function ` performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` of the UIAutomation class?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, functional-testing, ios-ui-automation

I am automating some test cases for an iPhone app and I am using the UIAutomation class. I want to use the function `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout`, which I believe runs some external script. But I cant use it. I have the following code:

```
#import "revision3.js"
#import "tuneup/tuneup.js"
test("script call", function(target, app){
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var host = target.host();
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("fwasim/Desktop/registration.js, ["null"], 5);

UIALogger.logDebug("exitCode: " + result.exitCode);
UIALogger.logDebug("stdout: " + result.stdout);
UIALogger.logDebug("stderr: " + result.stderr);
});
```

The instrument console says:

> Error: launch path not accessible.

I have searched on the internet but  there seems to be very scarce resources on UIAutomation class and more specifically on the above function. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout()` method on the host is for executing shell programs not JavaScript. That error message is telling you that it can't find an executable command at the path you gave.

Here's how you could execute a command with that method:

```
var result = host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/whoami", [], 5);
```

That executes the `whoami` command that lives in the `/usr/bin` directory. That command just prints out the logged in username which you can get at with `result.stdout` as you're already using.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, though. From the looks of the script you were trying to execute (`fwasim/Desktop/registration.js`), are you just trying to run some registration tests that are in a different file? If so, there's an easier way to do that. Just type this:

```
#import "fwasim/Desktop/registration.js"
```

That tries to import that JavaScript file as if it was relative to the directory of the script file that is running. You'd only need `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout()` if you're trying to execute an external shell script or something like that. It's not for executing JavaScript inside UI Automation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was actually trying to get the `performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout() ` function working and see how it works. I didn't know that this function could be used only to run shell programs, instead I had thought this could be used to run any piece of code. My eventual goal was to run an external script from UIAutomation which would perform some action that required me to exit the app I was testing. For example a testcase requires me to add a new contact to the address book and check for a popup within the app. I wanted the script to do things like this.